# Cannot call Elements in ChildLayout

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Hi This is my LayoutCode

```html
<RelativeLayout>
....

<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/up_Conpass"
        android:layout_above="@+id/sign_up"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        >

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/Checkbox"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textColor="#ffff"
            android:text="text"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Checkbox"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Unfortunetly I somehow can not call the two elements CheckBox and TextView in Java. Please help me. Thank you very much in advance :)

EDIT: findViewById is not working somehow

Comment: What exactly do you mean by call here?? Edit your question with proper detail .

Comment: like this in the Activity  findViewById(R.id.Text); is not working?

Comment: Oh yes, somehow findViewById is not working

Answer (score 0):

Okay, as it seams, rebuilding the project solved everything. 
Thank you to everyone commenting to this question :)